# Only __iter__ implemented as generator-func, want to use next()

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I have a class with `__iter__` defined like below:

```
class MyIterator:

    def __iter__(self):
        for value in self._iterator:
            if is_iterator(value):
                yield from value
            else:
                yield value
```

I want to do `next(my_iterator)` but I have to implement `__next__` to do so. But it would change this simple implementation to a fairly complicated one - or actually I don't know how to implement this instead of defining `__iter__` as a generator function.

Generally spealing, if `__iter__` is implemented as a generator fuction which might be difficult to be done without generator, how should I do if I want to use `__next__`?

Note: Apparently, `next(iter(my_iterator))` works, but I don't want to do it.

Comment: You need to explain more about how you intend the iteration to work.  You could write a `__next__` that just returns `next(iter(self))`.  If that doesn't do what you want, then you need to explain what you want the actual behavior to be.  In particular, note that by calling `__iter__` multiple times, you can get multiple separate iterators, but if you intend to use `next` directly on your object, then you can really only have one iterator.

Comment: Well, you've given me the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want something similar to [itertools.chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable). If a value you iterate is also iterable, expand that before continuing. So, `[1, [2,3,4], 5]` becomes `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is supposed to be an iterator, it should not have its `__iter__` method implemented as a generator function. That makes the class iterable, but not an iterator. An iterator's `__iter__` method is supposed to return itself.

If you really want your class to be an iterator, try something like this:

```
class MyIterator:
    def __init__(self, iterator):
        self._iterator = iterator
        self._subiterator = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            if self._subiterator is None:
                value = next(self._iterator) # may raise StopIteration

                try:  # could test is_iterator(value) here for LBYL style code
                    self._subiterator = iter(value)
                except TypeError:
                    return value

            try:
                return next(self._subiterator)
            except StopIteraton:
                self._subiterator = None
```

The `next(self._iterator)` call may raise `StopIteration`, which I deliberately do not catch. That exception is the signal we're finished iterating, so if we caught it we'd only have to raise it again.

This code uses a "Easier to Ask Forgiveness than Permission" (EAFP) approach to detecting iterable items within the iterator it's been given. It simply tries calling `iter` on each one and catches the `TypeError` that will be raised if they're not iterable. If you prefer to stick with the "Look Before You Leap" (LBYL) style and explicitly test with `is_iterator` (which is badly named, since it checks for any kind of iterable, not only iterators), you could replace the inner `try` with:

```
if is_iterator(value):
    return value
else:
    self._subiterator = iter(value)
```

I usually prefer EAFP style to LBYL style in my Python code, but there are situations where either one can be better. Other times it's just a matter of style.

Comment: Why making `self._subiterator` an instance variable instead of a local variable of the `__next__` method?

Comment: The `self` argument is a reference to the instance the method is being called on. So assigning to `self._subiterator` sets an attribute on the instance, rather than a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

As @BrenBarm commented, the apparent answer was to return `next(iter(self))`, or `next(self._iter_self)` by keeping `self._iter_self = iter(self)`. I couldn't just come up with it.

Answer (score 0):

- an iterator is an object with a `__next__` method that returns values until finally raising `StopIteration`.
- an iterable is an object with an `__iter__` method that returns an iterator.
- a generator is a special iterable created by python when a function or method include the yield statement.

In your example, `__iter__` has a yield so it is a generator. And that means it returns another iterable, not an iterator. That's why you have to do that strange `next(iter(my_iterator))` thing, and that doesn't work because it restarts the enumation each time.

How best to solve this problem depends on how you are using this class. You could create a generator function instead and then use `iter` to make iterators as needed:

```
import collections.abc

def is_iterator(i):
    return isinstance(i, collections.abc.Iterable)

def MyIterator(iterable):
    for value in iterable:
        if is_iterator(value):
            yield from value
        else:
            yield value

test_this = [1,2, [3, 4, 5], [6], [], 7, 'foo']
my_iterator = iter(MyIterator(test_this))
try:
    while True:
        print(next(my_iterator))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Or you can implement `__next__` instead of `__iter__`. But you can't use `yield` and have to return a value on each call until the outer iterator completes and raises `StopIteration`.

```
import collections.abc

class MyIterator:

    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self._iterator = iter(iterable)
        self._iterating = None

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            if self._iterating is not None:
                try:
                    return next(self._iterating)
                except StopIteration:
                    self._iterating = None
            value = next(self._iterator)
            if isinstance(value, collections.abc.Iterable):
                self._iterating = iter(value)
            else:
                return value


test_this = [1,2, [3, 4, 5], [6], [], 7, 'foo']
my_iterator = MyIterator(test_this)
try:
    while True:
        print(next(my_iterator))
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: Um, generator objects *are* iterators. And all iterators are required to be iterable. Every (correctly implemented) iterator should have an `__iter__` method that returns itself. The questioner's issue is that they've misunderstood what their class is. It's an iterable, but not an iterator. You'd get an iterator for it by calling `iter(some_instance)`, which will call the `__iter__` method and get the generator object (which is the iterator).